# Creating Agents from Agent Base Type during the simulation

Tags: java, agent, anylogic

I try to explain my problem as short as possible:
I got an AgentTypeOnly called customer, the data of the customer is in a database. I dont wan't to create all my agents at the beginning of the simulation. They should appear after a defined time, then they have to do a task and after the task is finished they have to dissapear (sink). At the moment i am creating them with a source block, but i am quite sure, that there is a better way to do it. For example a code in the main. 
Thanks for the help, I hope u get my question

Answer (score 0):

depending on the modeling technique you use, you can do it in different ways. When you use agent type only, you can only create agents using the source from the process modeling library.

If you use agent-based then instead of agent-type you have to use a population initially empty. then, for example if your agent population is called customers, you can create an agent whenever you want using the code add_customers();

None of these techniques is better than the other and it depends on your application